# How to determine link is clickable or not using selenium webriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Here is the scenario:

I want to click on the images on the site that are linked to their image and make sure no images on the site are linked to their image (e.g. no URL should end in JPG or PNG or GIF). For this, I`m clicking on each image using selenium web driver but many of the hyper-linked images can`t be clickable and click() event gets failed if we click on it.

Html Snippet code for such image:

```
<a class="alignright" title="Project Management & Business Analysis"      
href="http://ambitechstrous.com/wordpress/project-management-business-analysis/">
<img class="entry-image attachment-post" width="150" height="150" itemprop="image" alt="project-     
management" src="http://ambitechstrous.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/project-
management-150x150.jpg">
</a>
```

So, could any one help me how to handle such scenario in selenium web driver

PS: Also, Hyperlinked-Images are not clickable if we click on them manually in the site. Need workaround solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand from your question that you want to verify that whether image is clickable or not, if I am correct then I'd recommend to use following:

```
/**
 * To verify whether image link is clickable or not
 * 
 * @return true if image is clickable otherwise false
 */
public boolean isImageLinkClickable(String xpath){
       WebElement imgElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
       try {
          imgElement.click(); 
          return true;
        } catch(Exception e){
          return false;
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Priyanshu for your help! Yes.It worked and thanks for understanding my question. Great work!!

Answer (score 1):

driverobj.findElement(By.xpathExpression("//a[@href='http://ambitechstrous.com/wordpress/project-management-business-analysis/']")).Click();

Comment: elaborate more on your answer

Comment: @Anand Sorry to mention - This image can`t be manually clickable in the site as well.  Hence, need to know the workaround solution how to determine link is clickable or not.